# Laravel Validator::validateString|max does not exist Error

Tags: validation, laravel-5, dimension

In my Laravel 5.6.33 application I need to check dimension of an uploaded file with rule

```
    'avatar' => [
        'string|max:50',
        Rule::dimensions()->maxWidth(96)->maxHeight(64)->ratio(3 / 2),
    ],
```

But I got error:

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateString|max does not exist.
```

In declarations of rules I added a line:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

But I have the error anyway...

What did I miss?

MODIFIED 2 :
I see point in your comments:
I have file input with js function on file selection

```
<input type="file" style="display: none" ref="file_input" accept="avatar/*" @change="onImageSelected">
```

and when I selecte a file I keep it in this.user_avatar_url var and show on the form

```
    onImageSelected(event) {
        this.is_page_updating = true
        const files = event.target.files
        let filename = files[0].name
        this.user_avatar = filename;
        if (filename.lastIndexOf('.') <= 0) {
            return alert('Select valid avatar !')
        }
        const fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            this.user_avatar_url = fileReader.result
        })
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        this.is_page_updating = false
    },
```

the user_avatar_url has comntent like

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN
...
LSOiCLN/wIWijWu5oCk7wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

and setting the rule :

```
'avatar' => [
    'string',
    'max:100',
],
'avatar_url' => [
    Rule::dimensions()->maxWidth(2896)->maxHeight(2864),
],
```

I have the same error. Looks like that is wrong way...
Which is the correct way?

Comment: You didn't show us your full validation code...

Comment: what input you was validating? is it a string input?

Answer (score 3):

You should write it like that:

`'avatar' => [
        'string',
        'max:50',
        Rule::dimensions()->maxWidth(96)->maxHeight(64)->ratio(3 / 2),
    ],`

Comment: your answer is good, though it left me wondering... is it a string.. or is it an image..

Comment: my answer is about syntax, i also wonder about validating file as a string

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED 2 block of my first post.

Comment: change 'avatar_url' for 'user_avatar_url' in validation rules